# Show that a group of order $p^nm$ where $p>m$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ a group of order $p^nm$, with $p$ a prime number, $p>m$ and $m, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $G$ is a group is not simple.

Comment: I can has grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) Sylow theorems

2) How many Sylow $\,p-\,$subgroups can there be?

3) A Sylow $\,p-\,$subgroup is normal iff...?